# Android ProgressDialog fading background disappears Nexus 4 platform 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem occurs with Nexus 4 device with 4.2.1 platform. When simply calling following code in `Fragment`:

`ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "test", "test");`

Dialog shows ok and background dims, but immediately when dimmed, it dims off leaving background transparent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ProgressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: I want the dim effect, but it should not go off.

Comment: Try this:
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=1.0f; 
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

Comment: Now the background dims to 1.0f value, but when dimmed it dims off to transparent.

Comment: You try this:

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

Comment: Didn't help, but I tested very same package in another nexus 4 phone and it worked, so this phone must be broken or hacked or something.